# How to create a frontend custom page module with view template files in magento 2.3

Tags: module, layout, template, frontend, magento2.3.3

I have doubt as how to create Frontend Module with View template files. I have created Module using this reference Magento Documentation "https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-page/". In this Documentation they have Completed till the Controller section, they haven't explained as how to pass the collected data to view->frontend folder.

Please find the below code for creating frontend module

**File path:app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="salesperson" frontName="salesperson">
            <module name="VendorName_ModuleName"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**File path:app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Controller/Login/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Login;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
{
       $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
       parent::__construct($context);
}

    public function execute()
    {
        return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    } 
}
```

**File path:app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/salesperson_login_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="app_login_page" template="VendorName_ModuleName::salesperson_login_index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**File path:app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/salesperson_login_index.phtml**

```
<h1>Template file for Frontend Module</h1>
```

After creating all the above steps, I called the URL as **http://domainname.com/salesperson/login/index** , It just bring the store default header and footer content without our template code.

Someone help me as to Create View files and pass the data from controller to view files in Magento Custom Frontend Module!!!

Thanks in Advance :)

Regards, 
Hari

Comment: This will help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297919/crud-operation-step-by-step-with-example/299545#299545

Comment: @ChiragParmar , 
I am asking regarding Frontend View Module. We are not able to get the template page design while loading the frontend URL. The page didn't load the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Name of the module is defined as **VendorName_ModuleName**

it is necessary to create etc folder and add the module.xml file

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

***module.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

we will add registration.php

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName**

***registration.php***

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

we will create a controller to test module but Before create a controller, we will create a route for VendorName_ModuleName module.

To add route, it is necessary to create routes.xml file

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="salesperson" id="salesperson">
            <module name="VendorName_ModuleName"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Then, we will continue to create the controller and action

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Controller/Login**

***Index.php***

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Login;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action {

    private $pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
        return $page;
    }
}
```

now we create a block file

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block**

***Index.php***

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Index extends Template
{

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getNameshow()
    {
        $name = "hello i am come from block";
        return $name; 
    }
}
```

Now we add phtml file

**app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\view\frontend\templates**

***salesperson.phtml***

```
<h1>Template file for Frontend Module</h1>
<h2> <?php echo $block->getNameshow(); ?> </h2>
```

now last we add Layout file

**app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\view\frontend\layout**

***salesperson_login_index.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Index" name="show_phtml_data" template="VendorName_ModuleName::salesperson.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

run commands

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento c:c
```

After creating all the above steps, you called the URL as http://domainname.com/salesperson/login/index

if you have 404 page not found error then you have to enable your module **VendorName_ModuleName**.

And we will enable this module in this step

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

You should see the module is disable now:

List of disabled modules: **VendorName_ModuleName**

Follow exact guide to enable the module right now, let run the command as:

```
php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_ModuleName
```

After this step,

run commands

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f 
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: I have also updated the xml file with your content, the only difference is you have added layout='1column' as the page attribute. After updating the XML page content with your code, I have tried the commands you have mentioned also....Its not still working. 
Can you tell me what else I am missing still....I am getting till the controller, but it is not moving forward to View folder Layout xml file and template phtml file.

Comment: @hari I will find problem and Update answer soon

Comment: Msquare, I want to get this clarified quickly. Since I want to create many frontend view pages using (Controller, Block, Layout and Templates) for my new website.So can you please check and let me know ASAP.

Comment: @hari  let me know the above solution is working or not for you?

Comment: Msquare,  Thanks the above code works well...Thanks for helping me Msquare... :)

Comment: @hari if it's works so please accept answer or vote up.