# How do I unit test phtml?

Tags: magento2

I have a very simple phtml file like

```
<?php if ($block->getCondition()): ?>
foo
<?php else: ?>
bar
<?php endif; />
```

I want to write an automated test to check if block->getCondtion is true we render foo. How can I write a such test?

Comment: Can you show getCondtion() function which are you use.

Comment: @Msquare getCondition is not relevant here - I already have test for that. question is whether I can have test for phtml

Comment: Try this line https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301779/how-to-create-a-frontend-custom-page-module-with-view-template-files-in-magento/301947#301947

Comment: nono I know this code works. I just want to write unit test with phpunit

Comment: You don't need to unit test an if else statement; every one knows it works. If you want to test any thing at all, test the block.